# Modal popup works in FireFox but not other browers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, modal-dialog

I've developed a modal popup, which makes a popup screen, when clicking on a button.

It's either the AddToBasketButton click event, or the AskqlnkBtn click event which will open the window.

My code works perfectly in FireFox, but not in Internet Explorer / Chrome.

There is no visible JavaScript errors when running the code (as far as I can tell).

When clicking the links in the old browsers, the screen gets darkened, so the loadPopup must work somehow.

**See the problem yourself:**

If you want to experience the code on my website, [you can see it here.](http://www.hcemballering.dk/omsnoeringsmaskine) . If you go down to the "Læg i kurv" button, then you can try it out for yourselves.

**Any ideas what could be wrong?** I've been looking at it for some hours, and have no clue!

**My code**:

```
function loadPopup() {
        //loads popup only if it is disabled  
        if ($('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state") == 0) {
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').css({
                "opacity": "0.7"
            });
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').fadeIn("medium");
            $('#<%=ReportError.ClientID%>').fadeIn("medium");
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state", 1);
        }
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if ($('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state") == 1) {
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').fadeOut("medium");
            $('#<%=ReportError.ClientID %>').fadeOut("medium");
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state", 0);
        }
    }

    function setOrdering() {
        $("#contact-headline").text('Bestil produkt');
        $("#contact-messagelbl").text('Evt. kommentar');
        $('#<%=ContactTypeHiddenLbl.ClientID %>').val("bestil");
    }

    function setQuestions() {
        $("#contact-headline").text('Stil spørgsmål');
        $("#contact-messagelbl").text('Indtast dit spørgsmål');
        $('#<%=ContactTypeHiddenLbl.ClientID %>').val("spørgsmål");
    }

    function centerPopup() {
        $('#<%=ReportError.ClientID%>').center();
    }

    function resetContactControls() {
        $('#<%=ContactMailBox.ClientID %>').val('');
        $('#<%=ContactPhoneBox.ClientID %>').val('');
        $('#<%=ReportMessageBox.ClientID %>').val('');
        $('#<%=AskQuestionProductBtn.ClientID %>').show();
        $('#contact-statuslbl').val('');
    }

    jQuery.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position", "absolute");
        this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) +
            $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
        this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +
            $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
        return this;
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mouseIsInside = true;

        $('#<%=ReportError.ClientID%>').hover(function () {
            mouseIsInside = true;
        }, function () {
            mouseIsInside = false;
        });

        $("body").mouseup(function () {
            if (!mouseIsInside) {
                disablePopup();
            }
        });

    });

        $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state", 0);

        $('#<%=AddToBasketButton.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            resetContactControls();
            centerPopup();
            loadPopup();
            setOrdering();
        });

        $('#<%=AskqlnkBtn.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            resetContactControls();
            centerPopup();
            loadPopup();
            setQuestions();
        });

        $('#<%=PopupCloseLnk.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            disablePopup();
        });

        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                disablePopup();
            }
        });


    $(window).resize(function () {
        centerPopup();
    });
```

Comment: Why invent when you have jQuery UI or showModalDialog ?

Comment: Mplungjan: Now, that's a good question! Project was written before jQuery UI was widely known, and now I am trying to fix stuff. Would probably be (way) easier to use those... True!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused by how you are positioning the element. You are positioning it sort of as if it was supposed to be fixed. Try using this for the center code.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position", "fixed");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + "px");
    return this;
};
```

I changed to `position:fixed` and removed `scrollTop`. You don't want it positioned absolutely as that would mean it would scroll with the page.

**EDIT:** If you're still having trouble getting it working either use the dev tools to inspect the element and related styles to see what is going on or add this to the function to see what your `top` and `left` are being set to:

```
alert(Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + "px");
alert(Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + "px");
```

Comment: You are probably right! I tried using that code, and now it doesn't work in FireFox either.. But it's probably the position method!

Comment: Ok, problem was it was positioned inside a table element, and the absolute positioning was looking at the upper left part of that table, and not the whole screen :-)